# Could a person in Victorian UK be in charge of their own money at 18 years old?

Tags: 19th-century, law, victorian, inheritance

Could a male or female in Victorian UK be in charge of his or her own money at 18 years old? (Circa 1888) Could a legal guardian argue in court that since the age of majority was 21, he should be in charge of the money? My research shows that Victorian fiction abounds in characters who come into money at some stage during their childhood, and it's often their parents or guardians who control it until they are adults. Here is where I'm stumped. If he or she were 18, would it be a useless argument to make that they were in charge of their own money?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: Wikipedia has a clear agenda on this issue, so i wouldn't trust its statements even as far as I could throw a house.

Comment: Please specify a single year of interest. At a minimum the law was change by Act of Parliament in both [1870](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Married_Women%27s_Property_Act_1870) and [1882](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Married_Women%27s_Property_Act_1882), so the answer will change accordingly.

Comment: From the Wiki: "Women's rights were extremely limited in this era, losing ownership of their wages, all of their physical property, excluding land property, and all other cash they generated once married."[1] 

So it looks possible for a woman to own property before she marries and to own land property if she is married. Not sure about the age limit.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - Could you provide an alternate source that Marie could use as preliminary research?  What is a good basic source that would summarize the property rights of women that doesn't have the bias to which you refer?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: there are myths surrounding this issue. My take would be that once OP specifies a single year of interest, the question be accepted as presented. We would be providing a service by unwinding the myths here on the site.

Comment: I'm very interested in the issue raised by @stupidstudent and implicitly by Maire - are there cases where a woman can control property? What were the property rights of unmarried women? I know Scottish inheritance rules were different for titles, but I'm not familiar with property rights.  Let's document the basics, and then explore the interesting edge cases that will get Maire the desired information.  Or is the best example a woman whose property is controlled by a sympathetic (or blackmailed) lawyer?

Comment: I think if the aforementioned authors were stretching credibility it would have been noticed in studies of the works. My question has more to do with juvenile rights, if any. I could have said 'male' instead of female. I know the age of majority was 21.

Comment: Please specify a single year of interest. The laws and customs were in flux through the entirety of Victoria's reign. Questions must be phrased so as to at least allow for the existence of a definitive answer.

Comment: Maire's question has a second interesting facet - could the legal guardian expressly yield control?   I think the question is quite interesting; my comments are only designed to ensure that the question gets all the attention I think it deserves.

Comment: Thank you Mark, and Pieter, you asked the year of interest, it's Late Victorian, around 1888.

Comment: One further complication is that different legal systems applied in different parts of the UK.  Note, for example, that the [Married Women's Property Act 1870](http://statutes.org.uk/site/the-statutes/nineteenth-century/1870-33-34-victoria-c-93-married-womens-property-act/) applied in England and Wales, and in Ireland. However, para 16 of the Act stated explicitly that "*This Act shall not extend to Scotland*".

Comment: Potentially useful breadcrums [Wealthfare](https://www.qmul.ac.uk/geog/news/2017/items/keeping-it-in-the-family-inheritance-in-victorian-and-edwardian-britain.html) [land](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3743895?seq=1)

Comment: I'm also curious to know if there is a division between real property and chattel property.

Comment: [trust](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1dae/af24217f44ad59d4d746cf236fdc33c12c78.pdf), " contains some useful references, but I cannot copy and paste; recommended reading.  (no silver bullet, but I suspect it might be useful in finding a solution)

Comment: "Trusts were a common tool by which to ensure that children benefited, in time, from wealth left behind by a parent. On the death of a property owner, the majority of his or her wealth would pass to appointed trustees. When the deceased property owner’s spouse died, or when children had reached adulthood, the property held in trust was divided or sold off by the trustees and shared, usually equally, between all surviving children." _[gmul.ac.uk](https://www.qmul.ac.uk/geog/news/2017/items/keeping-it-in-the-family-inheritance-in-victorian-and-edwardian-britain.html)_

Comment: It was certainly possible for people, of any geneder and any age including 18,  in Victorian UK to be so poor that the only money they had was in their pockets, or maybe stashed in a secret hiding place only they knew about.  "During the mediaeval era and the era of feudalism, in England the age of majority for males was 21 and for females 14 if married and 16 if single.[2]"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_majority_(England)   So I guess an 18 year old woman in Victorian UK would have some rights, but I don't know how much she would be legally in control of her property.